# compare timestamp from auto_now format of django in java

Tags: java, django

I am working on a django and java project in which I need to compare the time in django to the time in current time in java.

I am storing the enbled_time in models as :

**enabled_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, default=timezone.now())**

The time gets populated in the db in the form :

*2017-02-26 14:54:02*

Now in my java project a cron is running which checks whether enabled_time plus an expiry time is greater than the current time something as:

```
Long EditedTime = db.getEnabledTime() + (expiryTime*60*1000); //expiryTime is in mins 
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - EditedTime > 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Here db is the database entity for that table.

But *db.getEnabledTime()* gives a result '2017'. What am I doing wrong?

PS: **I am storing time as Long which seems unsuitable to me**. Can someone suggest which datatype should I choose or does it work fine?

Comment: What exactly is db? What exactly does the db.getEnabledTIme() does? It might help to provide more clues. As for Time in Long, it seems fine to me, especially for counting time since epoch.

Comment: db.getEnabledTime() means I am getting the time from database.